# jar file for Session Class

Tags: java, couchdb

I have the below code from http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Getting_started_with_Java

```
Session s = new Session("localhost",5984);
Database db = s.getDatabase("foodb");

Document doc = db.getDocument("documentid1234");
doc.put("foo","bar");
db.saveDocument(doc);
...
```

I wonder which jar file contains Session class. I found https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Session.html?is-external=true but it isn't what I need.

Have you got something in mind?

Comment: Since it's a CouchDB tutorial, I would look in the CouchDB JARs

Comment: This is: [https://couchdb4j.googlecode.com/svn-history/r46/trunk/javadoc/com/fourspaces/couchdb/Session.html](https://couchdb4j.googlecode.com/svn-history/r46/trunk/javadoc/com/fourspaces/couchdb/Session.html)

Comment: Of cource you are correct ! :)  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What is the full name of this class Session as there might be multiple session classes.You can use `Ctrl+Shift+T` in eclipse to open your class and check the jar where it lies.
You can also find the jar for a class at runtime by using this

```
 CodeSource src = MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource();
 if (src != null) {
 URL jar = src.getLocation();  }
```

It works for all classes except classes loaded by bootstrap classloader

Comment: I need to download the jar. I don't have it. Thank you for you anaswer